# Naming abstract classes

Tags: php, oop

Do you think it's a good practice to differentiate abstract from non-abstract classes by giving their name a prefix or a suffix? What are the most common practices when it comes to that?

Here are a few "formats" I've been thinking about:

- Foo_Base
- Foo_Abstract
- Abstract_Foo
- Base_Foo

The use of underscores and letter case is irrelevant.

Edit: It seems like the Zend Framework uses a "Abstract" suffix ([source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Do you think it's a good practice to differentiate abstract from non-abstract classes by giving their name a prefix or a suffix?***

Unless you're following some convention, I would suggest not to attach this type of meta-data to your class names. Basically it clutters the code with information available elsewhere. To me it resembles [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) which is loathed by many programmers.

> ***Here are a few "formats" I've been thinking about...***

If I had to choose, I'd go with `AbstractFoo`.

According to these [PHP Coding Standard](http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/#classnames) you should really avoid `_`:

> ### Class Names
>
> - Use upper case letters as word separators, lower case for the rest of a word
> - First character in a name is upper case
> - No underbars ('_')
>
> **Justification**
>
> - Of all the different naming strategies many people found this one the best compromise.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> class NameOneTwo
>
> class Name
> ```

Comment: Here's where I come from. I've got an abstract class named `List_Field` and a few classes that extend it. The problem is, one of these extending classes is a great candidate for the name `List_Field`, but if that name is taken by the abstract class, the candidate in question can not use it so I'm forced to complicate its name.

Comment: Let the name of the concrete sub class reflect what type of `List_Field` it is. Say, for example `ArrayListField` or `LinkedListField`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not with a direct reference to a (1) derived class...

In a real situation there usually is a domain-specific collective name available.

But when there isn't I usually go with something like BaseViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Foo_Abstract or Abstract_Foo is a bad idea if you plan to use namespaces, as you will have Foo\Abstract, which is invalid.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Where does the "\" come from?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bad practice to name variables/functions/classes based on the type that it represents. `int myInt` is good for coding a quick example (perhaps in a classroom setting) but thats about it.

`abstract class AbstractClass` is too redundant and annoying to read. Let your programs/code say a lot in a concise way, and speak for themselves. From reading the definition I know its an abstract class I shouldn't need to be reminded in the name of the class. Focus on what purpose the class has in reference to the problem instead of what type of class it is.

This is the gist of things I got from [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

If you describe the project I can suggest good names that aren't redundant.

Comment: Does the same go for interfaces? Wouldn't you denote in some way that a file contains an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you actually want to specify a class to be abstract then you should use the abstract keyword in PHP

```
abstract class MyClass
{
    //**
}
```

If you want a way to check for abstract classes such as logical checks then you should create an interface like so:

```
interface IAbstract
{
}
```

and then declare the class with it

```
abstract class MyClass implements IAbstract
{
    //**
}
```

and then you can check like so:

```
if(MyClass instanceof IAbstract)
{
     //Abstract
}
```

This way you don't need to change your class names to suit the object types.

Comment: I do specify abstract classes as abstract. You seem to be against denoting the "abstractness" of the class in its name, but in your examples the interfaces have a "I" prefix. Would you comment on that?

Comment: because it's a single letter, it does not damage the class names by extending there length by 8 characters, I would never use something like `Interface_Abstract`

Comment: If the length of the prefix or suffix is the problem then how about the following name of an abstract class `AFoo`?

Comment: This is all preferences of the programmer, but personally I would not like to prefix with `A`, it would just not feel right to me, I do not have reason why, but its not something I would do with my applications.